# FormData with file object does not include the file when received by the back end

Tags: javascript, vb.net, file, multipartform-data, form-data

I am working on an small interface for file uploads in angular and attempting to send the file as form data. Looks like the file is non existent on the back end for some reason though.

When the file is selected I set it as the current file like this:

```
onFileChange(event){
    this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
}
```

In addition to that there is a name and type input the user fills out and then once the form is filled they can submit the form. Here is the code for my submit event:

```
onSubmit(){
    this.service.fileUpload(this.currentFileName, this.selectedFileType, this.currentFile).subscribe((rslt: any) => {
    alert('submitted!');
  })
}
```

And the onSubmit function calls the services fileUpload function passing in the name, type and file.

In the service function I am creating formdata and appending the 3 params like this:

```
packShipFileUpload(fileName: string, fileType: string, file: File){

  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  formData.append('fileName', fileName);
  formData.append('type', fileType);

  let f = formData.get('file'); // This is just me making sure that file is added to the formData

  debugger; //debugging to check formData values

  return this._http.post('/DataGetter/UploadFile', formData, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
  });
}
```

On the back I have an endpoint written in vb.net that so far just looks like this:

```
    Public Function UploadFile() As String

        Dim fileName = HttpContext.Request.Form.Item("fileName")
        Dim fileType = HttpContext.Request.Form.Item("fileType")
        Dim file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Item("file")

        Console.WriteLine(fileName) //break point here and I inspect the form items.

        Return ""

    End Function
```

I have ran through with debuggers attached to both the browser and back end application and even made attempts in my js to get the file object from the form data using `formData.get('file')` and I have verified that the file is added to the formData on the front end. For some reason though the back end always is completely missing that item from the formData.

[image: debugging on the front end the contents of 'f' in variables]

[image: And the file missing on the backend]

I have seen several other questions on SO that seem to have similar issue but I have not yet found one that has helped to get this fixed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this issue was related to the way that I was reading the file from the input. I was just assigning the file like this:

```
onFileChange(event){
    this.currentFile = event.target.files[0];
}
```

I revised this function to make use of async/await and the onload event.

```
async onFileChange(event){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        this.currentFile = reader.result;
    }
    await reader.readAsDataUrl(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

This gets the file data as a string. I was able to remove the first part of the string that is basically a label and the rest of the string is base64 file data which I packaged in JSON and sent to the server for processing. I sent this to a C# backend and converted to a byte[] like this:

```
byte[] binData = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
```

and then saved it to sql server as an image.

I apologize for not posting more of that code but I have since made many additional changes to allow for multi file upload using promises and added a lot more to the backend that is handling other data aside from just the file. I don't think those changes will be relevant to this post. I did want to at least post something as an answer here.

Hopefully it might save a bit of time for someone in the future.